# Laravel Passport Access Token Always Unauthenticated error

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

When I test the access token using postman, it always return user unauthenticated when accessing `http://passport.dev/api/user`. I check all the spaces of access token,  the right headers, Authorization Bearer token but still user unathenticated

Answer (score -1):

After a series of test and debugging, I got a simple answer,  I found out that all my configurations and setup with laravel passport are correct, upon checking the Authorization is not being set in the header. By adding this in htacess if using apache

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

It fixed the problem and saved me from annoying delimma.